# How can I hide the "popular topics" in Protostar template?

Tags: templates, default, template-manager

How can I hide the "popular topics", "recent articles" and "user access login" in default Protostar template? I need to edit the related index.php file of the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of Joomla as a Content Management System is that you should generally be able to update the content and look of the website without having to edit code.

You can likely disable or delete the modules you mention by logging in to the back-end of the website at www.yourwebsite.com/administrator and going to Extensions -> Modules.